# How to get the value of dynamic created EditText in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, dynamic-programming

I am building an android application where I am creating dynamic EdittextView. I need to display the sum of integer enter in it by the user. Below is my code to create Dynamic EdittextView:

> ```
> for (int i = 1; i < ZipRunApplication.ConfigLeg; i++){
>         LayoutInflater inflater = null;
>         inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
>                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_money, null);
>         TextView droxTextView = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.dropTextView);
>         final TextView position = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.position);
>         final TextView Amount = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.Amount);
>         final EditText dropEditTextView = (EditText) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.dropEditext);
>
>         dropEditTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>             @Override
>             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>                 Amount.setText(dropEditTextView.getText().toString()); //             
>
>
>             }
>         });
>         droxTextView.setText("Amount to be pick From Drop " + String.valueOf(i));
>         position.setText(String.valueOf(i));
>         droxTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             }
>         });
>         container.addView(mLinearView);
>     }
> ```

Could any one help me getting the sum of the all the EdittextView created Dynamicly.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for:

> Could any one help me getting the sum of the all the EdittextView
>   created Dynamically.

You can maintain an ArrayList of EditText and then can iterate through them and get the text entered in each of them and find the sum.

As an example I have the following snippet:

```
LinearLayout layout;
List<EditText> concernedEditTexts;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.base_layout); // Base layout defined in xml

        concernedEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

        // Creating five EditTexts
        for(int i= 0; i< 5; i++){ 
            EditText text = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            layout.addView(text);
            concernedEditTexts.add(text); // Adding dynamically created EditText in the ArrayList
        }
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setText("Get Sum");
        layout.addView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int sum = 0;

                // Iterate through the List and find the sum
                for(EditText editText : concernedEditTexts){
                    sum+= Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                }
                Log.d("SUM","Sum is "+sum);
            }
        });
    }
```

Note: This code is kind of raw and needs a lot more validations, but should be enough to explain the concept.

In your example you will need to store every dropEditTextView in the List and then iterate through the list as shown in my example will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Integer.parseInt(dropEditTextView.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

setTag() to each EditText as i variable and take an arrarylist of size ZipRunApplication. when you write in edittext then in textchnage listener get tag value and convert to int. This value will tell you for which position in arraylist you are writing . then in that position of arraylist set Integer.parseInt(editTextString).

Answer (score 0):

Four tips:

1 - Here we get the childs by the parent:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof LinearLayout) {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < ll.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    if (ll.getChildAt(j) instanceof EditText) {
                        ll.getChildAt(j).setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

2 - Don't forget to parse the data you try to receive:

```
Integer.parseInt(mFocusedEditText.getText().toString());
```

3 - note:

`view.setTag()` <-> `View.getTag()`

4 - **And last but not least**: In terms of readability, maintainability and performance you will get to a point soon, where a `ListView`- or `RecyclerView` will fit your needs MUCH better (**so keep in mind: the above coding isn't a proper solution, even if it works**).

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and 
[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)